# my answer,efforts happened or not happened

Tags: meaning, usage

I have been teaching in a boarding school for about 6 month. This is secondary school. In which, I have found the students speaking English in a wrong way, in the sense that they ask "my answer happened or not happened?"
In my opinion, they are directly transleting from their mother tongue "Nepali".

Actually, they want to ask If the answer they have written is correct or not. If the efforts they have made is good or not. They want the responses from teachers.

So, Please tell me how can I correct their ways of speaking in this way as they are habituated to it?

Comment: You should write *Actually they want to ask **whether** their answer is correct or not* or ***if** their answer is correct or not*.

Comment: You've already used perfectly natural phrasing in your question text *(is correct or not)*. We wouldn't normally say a question *happened* - but even if someone *did*, they'd probably mean it ***was asked*** or ***came up*** (certainly not ***was correct***).

Comment: @fumbelfingers They always ask "sir my answer/drawing/idea happened or not?" They are habituated. What can I do now?

Comment: Tell me the Nepali word for what you described here. I'm from India. I might understand.

Comment: Mero uttar/ mero drawing / mero idea vayo ki vayana?

Comment: Ah, I do not get the last part, which is the important part here.

Comment: मेरो उत्तर/चित्र इत्यादि भयो कि भएन सर ?

Comment: It seems possible that these students lack the distinction between "this is correct" and "this is true".  How would they describe a photo-realistic painting of dragons and unicorns, as compared to a badly-proportioned stick-figure of a cow?  How would they describe a grammatically perfect lie, as compared to a barely-comprehensible truthful statement?  How do they describe anything in the future tense, which obviously hasn't happened yet but can still be expressed correctly or incorrectly at this moment?

Comment: मेरो उत्तर/चित्र इत्यादि भयो कि भएन सर ? Here 'भयो कि भएन?" means "Happened or not happened?" according to them.  This is not correct translation either. Any Nepali person in this forum would understand my post.

Comment: This question seems to boil down to *I know what my students **should** say, but they keep using incorrect phrasing. How can I make them use the correct form?* Which might be suitable on [Language Learning](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/), but I don't think it's a good fit here.

Comment: Wait, so, they'd describe "will you be our teacher next year?" as *happened*, but "you had teaching so did last year?" as *not happened*?

Comment: @fumbelfinger Thanks for commenting, who would migrate this question to Language Learing stachexchange please

Comment: @Gary Boton No , you didn't exactly udertstand my post.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of their phrasing, you should always respond with the correct phrase.

> Yes, it is correct

or

> No, it is not correct (or incorrect).

And make sure they are paying attention when you do.
You might also explain that "happened" only indicates a result (they answered a question), but not what that was (right/wrong, etc).